# Does Android Geocoder getFromLocation and getFromLocationName method obtain information from Google Maps database?

Tags: android, google-maps

I wonder if these 2 methods getFromLocation and getFromLocationName obtain information from Google Maps database ? Because I realized the results from those 2 methods and from Google Maps are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, they use the Google Maps Geocoder service.